# CSS transform limitation in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, css-transforms

I've stumbled upon a seemingly-arbitrary limitation to CSS `transforms` in Firefox (64.0.2). It appears that transformed elements do not render when when `translateY` > 8947848px.  See this [pen](https://codepen.io/brianhadaway/pen/vQzzBv?editors=0100) or the snippet below (in FF):

```js
window.scrollTo(0, 8947848);
```

```css
.container {
  background: dodgerblue;
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 10000000px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.transformed {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
  transform: translateY(8947848px);
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

.too-much {
  background: tomato;
  transform: translateY(8947849px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="transformed">
    <pre>translateY(8947848px)</pre> Visible in Firefox.
  </div>
  <div class="transformed too-much">
    <pre>translateY(8947849px)</pre> Not visible in Firefox.
  </div>
</div>
```

Chrome (expected behavior):

[image: Chrome rendering of behavior]

Firefox:

[image: Firefox rendering of behavior]

I know it's possible to accomplish this with `position: absolute` and `top: 8947849px` but I'm trying to squeeze out as much performance as possible in the containing app so I want to stick to [compositor-only](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/stick-to-compositor-only-properties-and-manage-layer-count) properties since the `transform` will change frequently.

My question is whether there are any workarounds for translating beyond 8947849px in Firefox?

Comment: Apparently, Firefox maxes out at 2^31 times 1/240 of a pixel. How about using `scale` too? (Haven't tried it myself though.)

Comment: I think its browser's scroll limit. If you scroll your window in `FF` then also it will hide the green element which is placed at `8947848px`. By the way I found [this](https://github.com/PepsRyuu/virtual-scrolling-tree/issues/2)